createInitializeGroupInstruction fails with InvalidInstruction - how can I make an NFT Collection using Token Extensions?
I am following Group, Group Pointer, Member, Member Pointer lesson, using the code from the solution branch.
I've successfully uploaded the off-chain group metadata to Irys (I needed to make the main image less than 100KB to fall under Irys free tier).
When I try and create the Token Group, this fails with Custom Error 0xC (12 in decimal) which seems to be InvalidInstruction:
const signature = await createTokenGroup(
  connection,
  payer,
  groupMintKeypair,
  decimals,
  maxMembers,
  collectionTokenMetadata
);

(createTokenGroup() is from the solution repo)
Logs are:
[
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success',
    'Program TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb invoke [1]',
    'Program log: GroupPointerInstruction::Initialize',
    'Program TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb consumed 2437 of 1199850 compute units',
    'Program TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb success',
    'Program TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb invoke [1]',
    'Program log: MetadataPointerInstruction::Initialize',
    'Program TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb consumed 2507 of 1197413 compute units',
    'Program TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb success',
    'Program TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb invoke [1]',
    'Program log: Instruction: InitializeMint',
    'Program TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb consumed 4211 of 1194906 compute units',
    'Program TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb success',
    'Program TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb invoke [1]',
    'Program log: Error: Invalid instruction',
    'Program TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb consumed 831 of 1190695 compute units',
    'Program TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb failed: custom program error: 0xc'
  ]

Judging from the order of instructions, the InvalidInstruction comes from createInitializeGroupInstruction()
How can I make an NFT Collection using Token Extensions?

If you're connecting to a local test-validator, you'll need to update to the newest 2.0.14, which includes the version of token-2022 deployed to mainnet. Earlier versions have an outdated version of token-2022 included.

Thanks @JonC. Leading a class this weekend so don't want to mess with my main dev machine but can test next week.

I had the same issue. Updating to newer version helped.
I had Solana 1.18.17. After update to 2.0.17 everything just works.

Yes that's what I've heard too - Token Group is fixed in newer versions of Solana/Anza. Marking this an an accepted answer, though I haven't had time to try this yet!
